# Change starting coordinate for svg line drawing?

Tags: svg

http://codepen.io/stevendavisphoto/pen/doVOLo

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
height="223.5px"
width="432.7px"
viewBox="-1 -1 433.7 225.5">
    <path d="M341.6,95.3c3.4-62.2-66.9-96.3-112.5-62.7C173.7-34.9,70.7,10.7,79.5,94.4C17.8,93.4-26.4,166,18,223.5
    l396.4,0C461.3,162.7,410.9,85.8,341.6,95.3"
    stroke="#fff"
    stroke-width="2"
    fill="none"
    stroke-dasharray=""
    stroke-dashoffset="0.00"></path>
</svg>
```

The direction of the drawing is fine, but I'd like it to start from the lower left point, not the random point in the right middle. Can you show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The path starts where the definition says it does - which is whatever point the artist started from.

The general solution is to load the image into a vector editor and rearrange the path components - or redraw the path - so that it starts where you want.

If the path is simple enough, and you are familiar with how SVG path definitions work, you can do it by hand.  As I have done below.  Otherwise you will need to use a vector editor.

```js
var $p = document.querySelector('svg path'),
    pLength = $p.getTotalLength();
// Clear any previous transition
$p.style.transition = $p.style.WebkitTransition =
  'none';
// Set up the starting positions
$p.style.strokeDasharray = pLength + ' ' + pLength;
$p.style.strokeDashoffset = -pLength;
// Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
// picks up the starting position before animating
$p.getBoundingClientRect();
// Define our transition
$p.style.transition = $p.style.WebkitTransition =
  'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
// Go!
$('#draw').on('click', function(){
  $p.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  setTimeout(function(){
    $p.style.strokeDashoffset = -(pLength);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body {background:black;}
svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="223.5px" width="432.7px" viewBox="-1 -1 433.7 225.5">
  <path d="M 18, 223.5
           l 396.4,0
           C 461.3,162.7,410.9,85.8,341.6,95.3
           c 3.4 -62.2 -66.9 -96.3 -112.5 -62.7
           C 173.7 -34.9, 70.7, 10.7, 79.5, 94.4
           C 17.8, 93.4 -26.4, 166, 18, 223.5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0.00"></path>
</svg>

<button id="draw">Draw!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-anchors-in-a-path

> Optionally, you can do this in Illustrator (or other vector editor)
>
> If your path is open:
>
> 1. Select the pen tool (P)
> 2. Click the last anchor of the path. The order will be reversed
>
> If your path is closed:
>
> 1. If the path is a compound path, skip to step 4
> 2. Select the path with the Selection Tool (black arrow, V)
> 3. Click on menu->object->compound path->make. The path will be turned into a "compound path"
> 4. Open the Attributes window (menu->window->attributes)
> 5. Use the "Reverse path direction" buttons (they are only available for compound paths).

Comment: Please add a little more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and got round it by making a tiny cut in the path. I created 3 new points and deleted the middle one. I then dragged the path so there was no visible gap. Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/stuartjnelson/pen/ENPGBM)

```
enter code here
```